# "This version of JustMock has expired!" after purchasing a license

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit, justmock

I recently purchased a license for Telerik JustMock.  The Telerik Control Panel shows JustMock under my list of Purchased products.  When I attempt to run my tests in Visual Studio's Test Explorer with the JustMock Visual Studio extension enabled I receive an exception saying:
`Telerik.JustMockExpiredException : This version of JustMock has expired!`

I have uninstalled all the Telerik Visual Studio extensions, uninstalled everything Telerik via Windows Programs/Features, then re-installed the control panel and then JustMock yet the problem persists.  Of note, when I re-installed the control panel it remembered my username/password so I'm guessing there is a configuration file somewhere caching my information incorrectly.

A possible root cause of this problem is that I was trialing JustMock under my personal email address but it was purchased by my company and assigned to my work email address.  I am currently logging into the control panel with my work address and see no other place to change that.

The same problem occurs when I run nunit.exe via JustMockRunner.exe.

Comment: Telerik probably has a support system that you can contact. They are most likely in a better situation to help you.

Comment: I asked it here in hopes that the answer would be public to help future people with a similar problem (Stack Overflow has amazing search engine ranking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work for Telerik.

Please follow meilke's comment.

Nevertheless there are two options you can try:

1. As the license is developer based, it's important what email you use for downloading the licensed version. You should use the email that is assigned as licensed developer when downloading JustMock. I guess you've received similar answer from the sales support team.
2. The second option can be if you have used the JustMock trial version and you have included a trial Telerik.JustMock.dll somewhere in your source-control system. Hence despite installing the licensed version, your tests run with the trial.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem was the second.  I had committed JustMock to a repo and was pointing at those.  I didn't realize the assemblies are what contained the license information, I assumed it was in a config file somewhere.

Comment: I had a trial version and had to uninstall it before installing the non-trial version for it to work. Thank you, the second one was right for me.